How do I apply a colorscale to Plotly's histogram using the y values?
The histogram displays a number of items per month, but it appears to be using the wrong axis (or something else entirely) for the colorscale. I cannot find any information about this issue anywhere online.
Here is my current histogram:

Here is the relevant code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors as pcolors

graph_dates = [
    # list of datetime.datetime objects, one per item
]
graph_counts = [
    # list of distinct month counts
]

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(go.Histogram(
    x = graph_dates,
    marker = {
        'colorscale': [[0, '#0000ff'], [1, '#ff0000']], #pcolors.sequential.Bluered,
        'color': [0, 1],
        'showscale': True,
        'colorbar': {
            'title': "Colors",
        },
        'cmin': 1,
        'cmax': max(graph_counts),
        #'autocolorscale': False, # does nothing
        #'cauto': False, # does nothing
        #'colorsrc': 'y', # does nothing
        'line': {
            # almost anything I put in here does nothing
        }
    },
    xbins = {
        'size': 'M1', # group by month
    },
))
figure.update_xaxes(
    range = [min(graph_dates), datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)]
)
graph = figure.to_html(include_plotlyjs=False, full_html=False)
context['graph'] = graph

Note: Please avoid using plotly.express and pandas.

If histograms are considered as one type of bar chart, a bar chart can be drawn with time series data on the x-axis and its frequency data based on the original data. Then, the coloring of the bar chart can be achieved by using a color-coded list, as in the example in the reference. It may take a little time and effort, but it can be done.
